# Shutting down the ActiveMQ Transactions

Tags: mule, activemq-classic

I am having a Mule flow invoking ActiveMQ,and I would like to handle the transactions inside mule,as below

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mapperQueue"
        connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN"/>
</jms:outbound-endpoint>
```

But with  this, the message is not getting delivered to the  Active MQ queue. If I remove the jms:transaction  it is.

So I assume it is messed with the transactions started by the AMQ.Is there a way to disable the transactions in the AMQ?I use AMQ 5.14.5

Comment: In your begin of your flow under Jms Inbound , have you used <jms:transaction action = "ALWAYS_BEGIN"?. In the above scenario,have you tried under jms outbound  <jms:transaction action="JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE"/>?

Comment: According to documentation:

-- Apply a transaction to an outbound connector when you want Mule to handle the outgoing operation as part of an existing transaction.